# When calling async function, the browser blocks the new tab (target _blank)

Tags: javascript, forms, asynchronous, async-await

I've a button that generates a token (async) when clicked, after the token is generated the user is automatically redirected to a site where this token is used for auth.

```
<Button type="submit" onClick={redirect}>
   Go to site with token
</Button>
```

The redirect function:

```
const redirect = async () => {
    const response = await api.getToken();

    if (response.isOk) {
       const form = document.getElementById('tokenForm') as HTMLFormElement;
       form.action = response.targetUrl ?? '';
       form.target = '_blank';

       const tokenResponse = document.getElementById('tokenResponse') as HTMLInputElement;
       tokenResponse.value = response.token ?? '';

       form.submit();
    }
};
```

With the following form with method POST:

```
<Form method="post" id="tokenForm">
    <Form.Input type="hidden" id="tokenResponse" />
</Form>
```

So when the token is recieved from the api, the user is redirected to the url specified in form.action and when form.submit() is posted.

The problem I'm having is that when the button is clicked, the browser blocks the new tab (target=_blank) because it takes too long to recieve the token from the backend api.

If I try this locally it works fine, the token generates within a few seconds and a new tab opens, but in production it could take up to 4-6 seconds to generate the token which cause the browser to block the new tab. I've added a setTimeout at the api that generates the token so I can simulate this locally and it blocks the tab if api.getToken() takes over around 3-4 seconds.

Comment: If the token is not being generated in a web worker then it will block, async or not. Aysnc on it's own is not parallel programming.

Comment: So I need to create a web worker that calls the api and returns the token?

Comment: Unless someone else can think of a better solution, yes.